# Access PDF file from with JAR if the user fails to select a RadioButton

Tags: java, jar

I would like to copy a PDF file out of my JAR if the user fails to select a Radiobutton.  The problem I am having is that the console reports java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:/home/geeky/workspace/TabSync/bin/ndg/co/uk/TabSync/nullpdf.pdf (No such file or directory) even though the file is there.  If I copy the path that is claimed as No such file... into Thunar then the file opens straight away so the path is correct.

The code is below:

```
    URL nopathbrain = getClass().getResource("/ndg/co/uk/TabSync/nullpdf.pdf");

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            try{
            //set the busy cursor while building the sync files
             setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.WAIT_CURSOR));

            if (radioButton1.isSelected()) {
                filepathbrain1 = txtPath1.getText();
                System.out.println(filepathbrain1);
            } else {
                System.out.println(nopathbrain);
                filepathbrain1 = String.valueOf(nopathbrain); 
            }
copysource();
```

copysource() looks like this

```
public void copysource() {
    try{

        File afile =new File(filepathbrain1);
        File bfile =new File(buildpath +"/documents/1.pdf");

        FileInputStream inStream = new FileInputStream(afile);
        FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(bfile);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

        int length;
        //copy the file content in bytes 
        while ((length = inStream.read(buffer)) > 0){

            outStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
        } //end while
        inStream.close();
        outStream.close();
```

Output of jar -tvf is:

```
 0 Sun Mar 31 09:51:56 BST 2013 ngd/
     0 Sun Mar 31 09:51:56 BST 2013 ngd/co/
     0 Sun Mar 31 09:51:56 BST 2013 ngd/co/uk/
     0 Sun Mar 31 09:51:56 BST 2013 ngd/co/uk/TabSync/
   806 Sun Mar 31 08:53:20 BST 2013 ngd/co/uk/TabSync/About$1.class
   556 Sun Mar 31 08:53:20 BST 2013 ngd/co/uk/TabSync/About$2.class
  4762 Sun Mar 31 08:53:20 BST 2013 ngd/co/uk/TabSync/About.class
  1802 Sun Mar 31 08:53:20 BST 2013 ngd/co/uk/TabSync/Help.class
   733 Sun Mar 31 09:52:54 BST 2013 ngd/co/uk/TabSync/Main$1.class
   735 Sun Mar 31 09:52:54 BST 2013 ngd/co/uk/TabSync/Main$10.class
  1117 Sun Mar 31 09:52:54 BST 2013 ngd/co/uk/TabSync/Main$11.class
  1117 Sun Mar 31 09:52:54 BST 2013 ngd/co/uk/TabSync/Main$12.class
  1117 Sun Mar 31 09:52:54 BST 2013 ngd/co/uk/TabSync/Main$13.class
  1117 Sun Mar 31 09:52:54 BST 2013 ngd/co/uk/TabSync/Main$14.class
  1117 Sun Mar 31 09:52:54 BST 2013 ngd/co/uk/TabSync/Main$15.class
  1120 Sun Mar 31 09:52:54 BST 2013 ngd/co/uk/TabSync/Main$16.class
  1120 Sun Mar 31 09:52:54 BST 2013 ngd/co/uk/TabSync/Main$17.class
  1120 Sun Mar 31 09:52:54 BST 2013 ngd/co/uk/TabSync/Main$18.class
  1120 Sun Mar 31 09:52:54 BST 2013 ngd/co/uk/TabSync/Main$19.class
   733 Sun Mar 31 09:52:54 BST 2013 ngd/co/uk/TabSync/Main$2.class
  1120 Sun Mar 31 09:52:54 BST 2013 ngd/co/uk/TabSync/Main$20.class
   735 Sun Mar 31 09:52:54 BST 2013 ngd/co/uk/TabSync/Main$21.class
   735 Sun Mar 31 09:52:54 BST 2013 ngd/co/uk/TabSync/Main$22.class
   735 Sun Mar 31 09:52:54 BST 2013 ngd/co/uk/TabSync/Main$23.class
   735 Sun Mar 31 09:52:54 BST 2013 ngd/co/uk/TabSync/Main$24.class
   735 Sun Mar 31 09:52:54 BST 2013 ngd/co/uk/TabSync/Main$25.class
   735 Sun Mar 31 09:52:54 BST 2013 ngd/co/uk/TabSync/Main$26.class
   735 Sun Mar 31 09:52:54 BST 2013 ngd/co/uk/TabSync/Main$27.class
   735 Sun Mar 31 09:52:54 BST 2013 ngd/co/uk/TabSync/Main$28.class
   735 Sun Mar 31 09:52:54 BST 2013 ngd/co/uk/TabSync/Main$29.class
   733 Sun Mar 31 09:52:54 BST 2013 ngd/co/uk/TabSync/Main$3.class
   735 Sun Mar 31 09:52:54 BST 2013 ngd/co/uk/TabSync/Main$30.class
  1120 Sun Mar 31 09:52:54 BST 2013 ngd/co/uk/TabSync/Main$31.class
  1120 Sun Mar 31 09:52:54 BST 2013 ngd/co/uk/TabSync/Main$32.class
  1120 Sun Mar 31 09:52:54 BST 2013 ngd/co/uk/TabSync/Main$33.class
  1120 Sun Mar 31 09:52:54 BST 2013 ngd/co/uk/TabSync/Main$34.class
  1120 Sun Mar 31 09:52:54 BST 2013 ngd/co/uk/TabSync/Main$35.class
  1120 Sun Mar 31 09:52:54 BST 2013 ngd/co/uk/TabSync/Main$36.class
  1120 Sun Mar 31 09:52:54 BST 2013 ngd/co/uk/TabSync/Main$37.class
  1120 Sun Mar 31 09:52:54 BST 2013 ngd/co/uk/TabSync/Main$38.class
  1120 Sun Mar 31 09:52:54 BST 2013 ngd/co/uk/TabSync/Main$39.class
   733 Sun Mar 31 09:52:54 BST 2013 ngd/co/uk/TabSync/Main$4.class
  1120 Sun Mar 31 09:52:54 BST 2013 ngd/co/uk/TabSync/Main$40.class
  4765 Sun Mar 31 09:52:54 BST 2013 ngd/co/uk/TabSync/Main$41.class
   723 Sun Mar 31 09:52:54 BST 2013 ngd/co/uk/TabSync/Main$42.class
  1185 Sun Mar 31 09:52:54 BST 2013 ngd/co/uk/TabSync/Main$43.class
   697 Sun Mar 31 09:52:54 BST 2013 ngd/co/uk/TabSync/Main$44.class
  1220 Sun Mar 31 09:52:54 BST 2013 ngd/co/uk/TabSync/Main$45.class
   995 Sun Mar 31 09:52:54 BST 2013 ngd/co/uk/TabSync/Main$46.class
   781 Sun Mar 31 09:52:54 BST 2013 ngd/co/uk/TabSync/Main$47.class
   733 Sun Mar 31 09:52:54 BST 2013 ngd/co/uk/TabSync/Main$5.class
   733 Sun Mar 31 09:52:54 BST 2013 ngd/co/uk/TabSync/Main$6.class
   733 Sun Mar 31 09:52:54 BST 2013 ngd/co/uk/TabSync/Main$7.class
   733 Sun Mar 31 09:52:54 BST 2013 ngd/co/uk/TabSync/Main$8.class
   733 Sun Mar 31 09:52:54 BST 2013 ngd/co/uk/TabSync/Main$9.class
  2097 Sun Mar 31 09:52:54 BST 2013 ngd/co/uk/TabSync/Main$Field1Listener.class
 47217 Sun Mar 31 09:52:54 BST 2013 ngd/co/uk/TabSync/Main.class
  1260 Sun Mar 31 08:53:20 BST 2013 ngd/co/uk/TabSync/FileFiltererpdf.class
  1260 Sun Mar 31 08:53:20 BST 2013 ngd/co/uk/TabSync/FileFiltererjpg.class
991552 Wed Jul 27 19:13:00 BST 2011 ngd/co/uk/TabSync/Coalition_v2.ttf
991552 Wed Jul 27 19:13:00 BST 2011 Coalition_v2.ttf
409717 Thu Mar 21 14:15:32 GMT 2013 nullpdf.pdf
```

The problem I am having is that when the radiobutton is not selected then the copy of the PDF from the JAR does not work.  If I provide a manual path to a file on my desktop then the copy works fine (so I am happy that copysource() works ok, it is just included for completeness).

EDITED HERE:

I am now trying to access the pdf via a temp file as it seems I should be using a Stream to get the resource, I am still getting file not found exceptions though.  Code:

```
//write the null file to tmp for copy
         try {
                java.io.InputStream iss = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/nullpdf.pdf");
                byte[] data = new byte[iss.available()];
                iss.read(data);
                iss.close();
                String tempFile = "file";
                File temp = File.createTempFile(tempFile, ".pdf");
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(temp);
                fos.write(data);
                fos.flush();
                fos.close();
            nopathbrain = tempFile +".pdf";
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("TEMP FILE NOT CREATED - ERROR in brainradiocheck");
            }
```

I think the temp file is being created ok, but how do I get its filepath returned as a string?  I want to set the filepath of the tempfile to nopathbrain.

Andy

Answer (score 0):

To access a resource jar I use this statement:

```
this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/es/app/firstTry/resources/button.jpg")
```

this returns a InputStream, so you could open it or copy to any directory.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I want to deal with the copy separately if possible (in the copysource() as described above). How would I do that using the solution you suggested?

Comment: EDITED:  Based of what you say I am trying to now create a temp file and then access it.  I am still getting fileNotfoundexception.

Answer (score 0):

```
//write the null file to tmp for copy
         try {
                java.io.InputStream iss = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/nullpdf.pdf");
                byte[] data = new byte[iss.available()];
                iss.read(data);
                iss.close();
                String tempFile = "file";
                File temp = File.createTempFile(tempFile, ".pdf");
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(temp);
                fos.write(data);
                fos.flush();
                fos.close();
            nopathbrain = temp.getAbsolutePath();
            System.out.println(tempFile);
            System.out.println(nopathbrain);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("TEMP FILE NOT CREATED - ERROR in brainradiocheck");
            }
```

Answered myself if anyone else is facing similar.